# I need to create a specific string from the data in shared preferences

Tags: java, android

I've created an app for a company, it allows the employees to fill in timesheets, I've got everything working perfect except I want to create an email string from the results of my shared preferrences.

To elaborate, In my shared prefs I have a load of gas metres with qtys against them, if they have been fitted they put a qty against them, I want to ask programmatically "if the shared pref has a number against it then show it in a string, if not don't show"

So the string might look like

E6 - 3
U16 - 7 
G4 - 2

Even though there are 10 metres in the list and I've read all shared preferences it will only show the one with numbers in them.

Sorry for the rubbish description but it's sometimes difficult to put what I need into words.

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 0):

```
Create a simple class named as "SessionManager" & create a function as below in that class:

public void saveCityValues(Context contxt, String cityResponse) {
        SharedPreferences fbPref = contxt.getSharedPreferences("CityData", 0);
        Editor edit = fbPref.edit();
        edit.putString("cityResponse", cityResponse);
        edit.commit();

    }

Use this function to save the data in shared preference as below :
SessionManager sm = new SessionManager();
            sm.saveCityValues(context,responseBody);

Use below statement to use that saved string :
    String city =
```

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences =caller.getSharedPreferences("CityData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String cityresponse = sharedpreferences.getString(key, "");

Answer (score -1):

You can use getString method of shared pref with default value as null. If returned value is null don't append the result to the final string.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: Hi there Thanks for the reply but that's the problem I'm having, how do I create the string from the results?

Comment: Value returned is string. You can create StringBuffer and keep appending your string to it.